# How to retrieve wallet's creation date via API of etherchain.org?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I've been searching for a way to retrieve wallet creation date and didn't found any good approaches so far.

What I've found is parsing `First seen` field (left-bottom corner) from [etherchain.org](https://www.etherchain.org/account/074976a8D5F07dA5DADa1Eb248AD369a764bB373) site.

I realize that this is not exactly what I'm looking for but at least something that nothing.

Does etherchain.org provide respective API for retrieving this value by issuing HTTP request or maybe you know better places where I can retrieve this data?

Answer (score 3):

"First seen" would be the date that the address was first *used*, and the first time any data related to it was stored in the blockchain.

A couple of things:

- All addresses exist. Always. The question is whether or not someone has generated the private key that equates to, and allows the use of, a given address.
- There's no way of knowing when a private key corresponding to an address was generated. It can be done offline. It can be done years in the past.

The only thing you can know for certain is when the address is first *used*, and therefore infer that someone holds the private key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know any API for retrieving this `first used` date value?

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the APIs provided by block explorers provide this information, I'm afraid. What you could do, as a bit of a hack, is get the paginated list of transactions for a given address using an API, and look at the timestamp on the oldest one. Might need to check if the address belongs to a contract first. (Perhaps?) This would give you when the first transaction was written to a block. It doesn't handle cases where that transaction was pending for any length of time. (e.g. It could have been pending for a week, or a year. Then your value is off target.)

Comment: https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts

Comment: Thanks for the link. How can I determine either transaction is pending or not?

Comment: If the transaction is in a block, then it's not pending. If it's not in a block, then it's pending.